# CSS Filter cancels element position

Tags: css, firefox, position

### [Demo page](http://jsbin.com/nocokivile/edit?html,css,output)

```css
body {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

div {
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;  /*  <---- ignored */
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Giving `filter:blur(1px)` (or any other [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)) to a parent of a positioned element makes the browser ignore the child's position.

Has anyone encountered that and know a way to fix this annoyance?

---

*Tested on FF48 beta / win7*

Comment: if we can give parent element height "height: 500px;".child position will work.

Comment: I have the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717289/). I submitted a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1650522) to Firefox and I'm also asking the W3C to [change the spec](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/402) for filters that have nothing to do with size/position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because absolutely positioned elements are positioned relatively to their [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details), which is established by their nearest positioned ancestor, or the initial containing block if there is no such ancestor.

Then, if you don't use `filter`, the containing block will be the initial one, which has the same dimensions as the viewport.

However, if you use `filter` on `body`, that will establish a containing block, even for absolutely positioned descendants. It will be like if you used `position: relative`.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Instead, I recommend setting the `filter` on `html`, and use `height: 100%` to make it as tall as the viewport.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
div {
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @vsync That was not the point of my answer. When I said "absolutely positioned", I included fixed.

Comment: But positioned `fixed` elements do not care about relative parents. they are relative only to the window itself, so this is in fact seems like a browser bug no?

Comment: @vsync No. Relatively positioned elements establish a containing block for absolutely positioned descendants, but not for fixed ones. `filter` establishes a containing block for fixed ones too. So the behavior is somewhat analogous to a relatively positioned container and an absolutely positioned descendant.

Comment: I wonder why is that? it seems like a spec decision which can screw up so much and there is no way to fix this

Comment: Because it's faster. For browsers it would be more expensive to make filter affect descendants whose containing block is established by an ancestor of the filtered element

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{ 
  -webkit-filter:blur(2px); 
  filter:blur(2px); 
  /* setting the viewport height on body */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div{
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Setting the body to min-height of viewport seems to work.

Comment: My demo was the most simple code and cannot be taken lightly since the actual code is much more complex. there is no body. there is no min-height that can be given.